# Spark 2.2.0 - Load a specific list of files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to load a specific list of files into Spark. I made a UDF which filters the list of files, so I obtained a `Seq<String>` with the files I want to load. I'm trying to use `public Dataset<Row> csv(scala.collection.Seq<String> paths)` [link to API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-scala.collection.Seq-) but for some reasons, it tells me "overloaded method value csv with alternatives: (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  (csvDataset: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame cannot be applied to (Seq[String])"

What am I missing here?

```
package main.scala.task

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object Test {

  def date_filter: (java.io.File, Int) => Boolean = (file: java.io.File, threshold: Int) => {
    val pat1 = "(\\d+)".r // Pattern to capture timestamp
    val matcher1 = pat1.findFirstMatchIn(file.getName) // Capture timestamp

    matcher1 match {
      case Some(matched1) => {if (matched1.group(1).toInt > threshold) {true} else {false}}
      case None => false
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val path = "/my_folder/Test"

    val now: Int = 1486022490
    var files = new java.io.File(path).listFiles.filter(p => date_filter(p,now)).map(_.getName).toSeq

    val df = spark.read.csv(files)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that you need to use [varargs](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/11/varargs.html) instead of passing a sequence of strings.

```
val files: Seq[String] = Seq("/path/to/file1.txt", "/path/to/file2.txt")
val df = spark.read.csv(files:_*)
```

Also, you linked to the Java docs instead of the [Scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@csv-scala.collection.Seq-) which might explain your confusion.