# Spark read multiple csv into one dataframe - error with path

Tags: dataframe, scala, csv, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm trying to read all the csv under a HDFS directory to a dataframe, but got an error that says its "not a valid DFS filename" Could someone help to point out what I did wrong? I tried without the `hdfs://` part as well but it says path could not be found. Many thanks.

```
val filelist = "hdfs://path/to/file/file1.csv,hdfs://path/to/file/file2.csv "
val df = spark.read.csv(filelist)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123964/spark-2-2-0-load-a-specific-list-of-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark 2.2.0 - Load a specific list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123964/spark-2-2-0-load-a-specific-list-of-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val df = spark.read.csv(filelist:_*)
```